# Pass value of Behavior Subject type to new post request in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass values of behavioural Subject type in Angular Post Request but getting this error :

> ```
> {_isScalar: false, observers: [], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null,…}
> ```

```
get currentID()
 {
    return this.UserService.ID;
 }
let data = {  id: this.currentID() };

 this.Service.getData(data).subscribe(data => {
```

> Service:

```
    ID=new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
```

value is available in this variable :

```
BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
closed: false
hasError: false
isStopped: false
observers: [Subscriber]
thrownError: null
_isScalar: false
_value: ....56568568
value: (...)
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`BehaviorSubject` is still an observable, and since I don't see what your service class is doing with the `data` variable, I'm going to assume that you don't want your id to be an observable still at that point.  In order to get the last value that was emitted by the `BehaviorSubject`, you will want to call the `getValue` method like so:

```js
get currentID()
{
    return this.UserService.ID.getValue();
}

let data = {  id: this.currentID() };

this.Service.getData(data).subscribe(data => {
```

Another approach you could take is compose your observable like:

```js
this.UserService.ID.pipe(
  map(id => ({id})),
  switchMap(data => this.Service.getData(data))
).subscribe(result => {
  ...
});
```

The second approach doesn't require you to unpack the `BehaviorSubject`, but instead, use it to compose a new observable stream that needs the BehaviorSubject and the service call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tried this with when calling `this.currentID()` it gives me this error `ERROR TypeError: this.currentChatID is not a function` but i'm able to get value using this code `this.UserService.ID.getValue();`

Comment: if you set it up as a `get` property (getter property), then you don't want to invoke it with `()` at the end.  If you just use `this.currentID` instead of `this.currentID()` it will work :)